# Google map showing skin color screen

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

[image: Its getting the current location but not showing on screen instead its showing this]

1. Viewdidload method

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
     selectedAdressType = "pickup"

       mapV.delegate = self
      styleOfMap()
      mapV.settings.myLocationButton = true
       mapV.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    //   self.pickupAddressTxtF.setLeftPaddingPoints(7)
       //self.destinationAddressTxtF.setLeftPaddingPoints(7)
       googleLocationTableV.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       googleLocationTableV.estimatedRowHeight = 50
       googleLocationTableV.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
       savedLocationTableV.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
       googleLocationTableV.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

       // Add footer for set pinn location
       googleLocationTableV.tableFooterView = AddFooterView()
       savedLocationTableV.tableFooterView = AddFooterView()
       redirectMap(to: Double("\(latitude)") ?? 0.0, lng: Double("\(longitude)") ?? 0.0)

       let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
       if userDefaults.object(forKey: "LocationInitialData") != nil {

           let retriveArrayData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:  "LocationInitialData") as? NSData

           let dataDic = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: retriveArrayData! as Data) as? NSDictionary)
           print(" saved response = \(dataDic!)")

           self.recentSerchList = dataDic?.value(forKey: "recent_search")as! NSArray
           self.savedLocationList = dataDic?.value(forKey: "save_address")as! NSArray

           self.savedLocationTableV.reloadData()
       }
       savedLocationTableV.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
       googleLocationTableV.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
     //  addressSerachApiCall()
       if Language.isRTL {
           pickupAddressTxtF.textAlignment = .right
       }

   }
   ```
2. Redirect Method

   ```
   func redirectMap(to lat: Double, lng: Double) {
       // [_mapView clear];
       let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
       let camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: position, zoom: 16, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
       mapV.animate(to: camera)
   }
   ```
3. Styling of map show "Unable to find style.json"

   ```
      func styleOfMap()  {
           do {
               if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                   mapV.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
               } else {
                   NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
               }
           } catch {
               NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: did you initialise google map key in app delegate?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are saving the App Language because i faced the same issue and i am getting this error due to incorrectly saving the value against "Apple Language" key.

Comment: self.userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                self.userDefaults.set(["ar","en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                currentLanguage = "ar" @MuhammadSalman

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue] + preferredLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

Comment: The Google Api key is not working by changing the google Api key its now Resolved MuhammadSalman